# Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Status code 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, cors, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as part of response headers when 403 HTTP status code returned from API Gateway ?

Solution

Below Swagger Configuration needs to be added for the Gateway.

```
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
  DEFAULT_4XX:
    statusCode: 403
    responseParameters:
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
    responseTemplates:
      application/json: "{\"message\":$context.error.messageString}"
```

Comment: which server u are using?
nginx/apache?
is it ec2

Comment: AWS API Gateway is returning the response, I figured it out by adding custom gateway response when 403 status code returned.